# How to properly check and see the result of jQuery code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I'm learning jQuery and trying to check some examples from a learning center. I've created html file and referenced jQuery there and a javascript code within script tags. I'm checking in the browser console but this code shows me not what I expect.

```
$.each([ "foo", "bar", "baz" ], function( idx, val ) {
console.log( "element " + idx + " is " + val ); });
```

It logs nothing and just returns the Array object itself. What I expect, I'm not sure, something like:

```
element 0 is foo
element 1 is bar
element 2 is baz
```

Also If you know how to import jquery in node.js please tell me how. I have a Python backgound so I think node.js is like Python interpreter.

Comment: node.js is server side, jQuery is client side. That's probably your main source of confusion .

Comment: It is working fine as you expected Please check your jquery reference

Comment: @Yogesh Sharma, it appears to be browser problem. It doesn't work on Firefox, but works fine in Developer Edition and Chrome. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not working with the dom you can setup your nodejs and test jQuery API inside the console.
After installing nodejs on your pc, you need:

- To install jQuery globally using `npm` package manager (usually it comes together with nodejs)

  ```
  npm i -g jquery
  ```
- Open console and go to the nodejs interactive mode typing

  ```
  node
  ```
- Load jQuery

  ```
  var $ = require("jquery");
  $(["foo", "bar"]).each(function (i, elem) { console.log(i, ": ", elem); });
  ```